# Check a file of HTTP URLs for HTTP response codes

Tags: url, hyperlink, broken-links

I need a way to check a file that contains links to see if any of them are broken. The file contains links to thousands of different URLs. I don't need to crawl or spider any further than the URLs that are in the file - we just need a HTTP request response for each URL.

Comment: Since you haven't specified a language, you're only going to get generic responses: 1. open file. 2. read file. 3. scan file contents for links. 4. issue HTTP `HEAD` requests for each link. 5. record http response codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html).

It does exactly what you need, assuming it's a web page, or a text file of links. You can control how deep it follows links.

Comment: I looked at Xenu but can't figure out what type of file it will open. Txt file did not work. I looked online also at the publicly made manuals to no avail for file type that Xenu will 'eat'.

Comment: Open of the options is open URL list which accepts a text file.

Comment: Nevermind: I did "File Open URL List (test)" and this allows text files. The "File Open" is obscure and asks for Xen files. Thank you and I apologize.

Comment: Yeah it's not the slickest app, but it works fairly well - be sure the set the max depth